# Will AI develop in hybrid ways?

Tags: ai-design, philosophy, applications

There are two general ways in which AI can interact with humans:

1. Implants of AI devices into human bodies or brains — Such implantation has already begun with health monitors and could grow to include cognitive access to general purpose digital computing.  Once such is accepted, it is possible that humans will emerge with behavior largely defined by its implants therefore qualify as a hybrid AI systems.
2. Embedding of AI systems into business or government organizations — It is possibliites that the behavior of organizations using AI systems for business decisioning will eventually be defined in behavior largely by those systems and would therefore qualify as a hybrid AI systems.

How probable are these possibilities, considering human history and current cultural trends in technology acceptance?

Comment: Regarding the second part of my question: The publicly available military plan of China for the next 5y announces a transition from informational guided warfare to an AI guided army. For example: Will there be a future moment in history, where in peace times the chinese AI system will decide to secretly start an attack on the power grids of the EU ?

Answer (score 1):

These two are not "general" ways in which AI interact with humans , especially not the first one. In fact most of the applications we have complex AI algorithms deeply rooted in them , your search engine , smart-reply , translating systems all employ some kind of "AI" or to be more specific "machine-learning" algorithms in them. and many organizations are already using business-intelligence systems which you can call "AI" in some sense.